# jquery post second time textbox is empty

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

i use this click event function for post data.for first time it works fine completely and for second time i check in debug mode gcX and gcY textbox value is empty but gcZone value is ok.why???????

```
 $(document).on('click', "#InsertGc", function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var url = '@Url.Action("SetGeographicCordinateList")';
            var X = ($.trim($('#gcX').val()));
            var Y = ($.trim($('#gcY').val()));
            var Zone = $('#gcZone option:selected').val();
            $.post(url, { X: X, Y: Y, zone: Zone, ActionType: true }, function (data) {
                if (data == "True") {
                    var p = "<tr class='tRow'> <td  id='gcX' class='tbody'>" + X + "</td><td id='gcY' class='tbody'>" + Y + "</td><td id='gcZone' class='tbody'>" + Zone + "</td>";
                    p += "<td class='tbody'><a href='#' title='حذف ' class='DelIcon' ></a></td></tr>";
                    $('#trGC:first').before(p);
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you making multiple instances of gcX and gcY after the first post? You do this `before` command. Does that overwrite the previous gcX and gcY? If not, you have duplicate elements with the same ID at the point.

Comment: that is right.i understand the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first time, you insert

```
<td  id='gcX' class='tbody'>" + X + "</td><td id='gcY' class='tbody'>" + Y + "</td>
```

Now you have two elements with id `gcX` and `gcY`, which are *not* empty.